# private method `select' called for ... error in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I looked at a few other posts on this but they don't fix my problem

Here is the code with .select in it causing the problem

Category_item controller

```
def show
  @category_item = Category.friendly.find(params[:category_id]).category_items.friendly.find params[:id]
  @key_values = CategoryItem.friendly.find(@category_item.id).select("catrgory_item_values.key, categroy_item_values.value") 
end
```

here is the model

```
class CategoryItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
  has_many :category_item_values, dependent: :destroy

     extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :name, use: :slugged
end
```

From the other similar questions they say to inherit from ActiveRecord::Base but my category item class already inherits from it.

I'm ultimately trying to get the keys and values associated to a category item sorted in a hash. Building this app to learn rails better so this is something I don't know how to fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `#find` you get an ActiveModel object, which doesn't have the `#select` method you expect.

Try:

```
Hash[CategoryItemValue.where(category_item_id: @category_item.id).pluck(:key, :value)]
```

Comment: I get the error: no such column: catrgory_item_values.key: SELECT catrgory_item_values.key, categroy_item_values.value FROM "category_items" WHERE "category_items"."id" = ? ORDER BY "category_items"."id" ASC LIMIT 1

Comment: Try this : `CategoryItem.friendly.where(id: @category_item.id).select(:key, :value).first`

Comment: the error:  undefined method 'friendly' for #<Class:0x007fcddb54d598> shows up on line `CategoryItemValue.friendly.where(id: @category_item.id).select(:key, :value).first`

Comment: I suppose you don't have a **friendly** scope. Try : `CategoryItem.where(id: @category_item.id).select(:key, :value).first`.

Comment: works but the output is #<CategoryItemValue:0x007fcddb7272d8> . Does that command store the keys and values in a hash or is there more i need to do?

Comment: You can get the values like this : `c = CategoryItemValue.where(id: @category_item.id).select(:key, :value).first` and then `c.key` and `c.value`

Comment: Just realised I also needed to change `id:` to `category_item_id:`. there are multiple keys and values assigned to one category item thats why i wanted all that are assigned to a category item to be in a hash. I feel like this only grabs the first it finds and stores the one in the hash thats why i wanted to see the hash to know if it grabbed them all. And thanks for helping so far!

Comment: If you want all the key/values, you can try : `CategoryItemValue.where(category_item_id: @category_item.id).pluck(:key, :value)`. You'll get an array of arrays. The first value of the arrays will be the `key` and the last the `value`.

Comment: Unfortunately i need them in a hash like ('key1' => '1', key2 => '2', 'key3' => '3') I'm doing this for the liquid gem that takes a hash of key values.

Comment: `Hash[CategoryItemValue.where(category_item_id: @category_item.id).pluck(:key, :value)]`

Comment: Your a mad genius thanks i learnt a lot from that! Its hard to know about all the little things like .pluck and turning it into a hash like that. One day i'll get there :)